# How to create a multi-line graph from a pivot table in Google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a pivot table which I couldn't generate a multi-line graph as desired.

[image]

How can I use this data to generate a lines-graph like this?

As can see in the image above, I couldn't create many colors, but only one line.

[image]

I want to have a drop down (or ability to filter by label) so x axis is `day` y axis is `D column values` and each domain has a different colored line.

In the pivot table, when a `label` doesn't have a row with some `domain-value` for some `day` it means domain has implicit 0% value for that label for that day. Can the graph deduce that without normalizing the pivot table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question

> I want to have a drop down (or ability to filter by label) so x axis is day y axis is D column values and each domain has a different colored line.

Try slicers. See the official docs : [Filter charts and tables with Slicers](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9245556?hl=en)

Another way to add a dropdown is to use cell validatition, but in this case you should use a formula or script that depends / will read the selected value.  Again, please see the official docs: [Create an in-cell dropdown list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: Thanks. i will try. Yet how do I create multi lines per a label (chosen in a slicer).